# OAuthGetRequestToken:signature_invalid error

Tags: ios, oauth, google-data-api

I try to use google data api and met difficulty at  OAuthGetRequestToken.
I follow the instruction: [requestToken](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#RequestToken)

I use GET and add query parameters after the url.

I create the base string for signature in this way:
GET&request url &query parameters(without oauth_signature) ordered by alphabetically

As I use HMAC-SHA1, I use the  "consumer secret" value to create the signature.

Finally, I use the url+query parameters, and the browser always returns :
signature_invalid
base_string:GET&https%3A%2＊＊＊＊＊＊

and I found the base_string is the same as the one in my code.

I don't know where is the problem and ask for help.
Below is my code:
(hmac_sha1 is right as I use sample data from Oauth to test)

```
#import "ContactTestViewController.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import "Base64.h"
#import "NSStringAdditions.h"
#import "NSData+Base64.h"
#define kAllContacts @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"

#define kOauthGetRequestToken @"https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken"

#define kOauthConsumerKey   @"oauth_consumer_key=***.net"
#define kOauthConsumerSecret        @"****/*****"
#define kOauthNonce @"oauth_nonce=457261624861626265724761686176"
#define kOauthSigMethod             @"oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1"
#define kOauthSignature             @"oauth_signature="
#define kOauthTimeStamp             @"oauth_timestamp="
#define kOauthScope @"scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
#define kOauthCallback              @"oauth_callback=http://****.net/index.html"
#define kOauthVersion               @"oauth_version=1.0"
#define kXOauthDisplayname          @""

@implementation ContactTestViewController

- (NSString *)parameterStrNoSignature
{
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInter = [currentDate timeIntervalSince1970];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@&%@&%@&%@%d&%@",
                 kOauthCallback,
                 kOauthConsumerKey,
                 kOauthNonce,
                 kOauthSigMethod,
                 kOauthTimeStamp,
                 (int)timeInter,
                 kOauthScope
                 ];

return str;
}

- (NSString *)hostEncode:(NSString *)str
{
NSString *str1 = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A"];
NSString *str2 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];

return str2;
}

- (NSString *)parameterEncode:(NSString *)str
{
NSString *str1 = [str  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%252F"];
NSString *str2 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%253A"];
NSString *str3 = [str2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
NSString *str4 = [str3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
return str4;
}
- (NSString *)hmac_sha1:(NSString *)key text:(NSString*)plainText
{

const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [plainText cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSString *hash = [Base64 encode:HMAC];//base64 

hash = [HMAC base64EncodedString];
[HMAC release];
return hash;
}

- (void)authTest
{
NSString *parameterNoSignature = [self parameterStrNoSignature];
NSLog(@"no signature parameters:\n%@",parameterNoSignature);
NSString *baseStringEncode = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"GET&%@&%@",
                              [self      hostEncode:kOauthGetRequestToken],
                              [self parameterEncode:parameterNoSignature]
                              ];

NSLog(@"base string encode:\n%@",baseStringEncode);

NSString *signatureStr = [self hmac_sha1:kOauthConsumerSecret 
                                    text:baseStringEncode];
NSLog(@"signature:\n%@",signatureStr);



NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@&%@%@",
                    kOauthGetRequestToken,
                    parameterNoSignature,
                    kOauthSignature,
                    signatureStr
                ];
NSLog(@"url string:\n%@",urlStr);
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

[self authTest];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry that the page looks so ugly and I don't know how to fix it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the key, you need [in pseudocode]: urlencode(utf8(oauth_consumer_secret)) + "&" + urlencode(utf8(oauth_token_secret))

Just using the oauth_consumer_secret is insufficient. If oauth_token_secret is empty, as it will be at the beginning of the OAuth process, that part will be empty *but you still need the & following the encoded consumer secret*.

Comment: thanks,you're right! But I am strange that google does not point it.